# reference request for a book on high dimensional probability and data analysis written for mathematicians

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question, information-geometry

I hope someone can help with this. I am a statistician looking for a good book on high dimensional probability and data analysis. Basically I am looking for the equivalent of Terry Tao's 2 volume set on Analysis, but for high dimensional probability. Let me qualify what I am looking for.

Now there are a bunch of books out there with these very words in the title. I will list some below. But most of these are geared towards just pure machine learning folks or computer science. So often books on high dimensional data focus on techniques like Principle Components Analysis or Lasso, etc., to analyze high dimensional data. In developing these models, the authors start off with strong parametric assumptions about exponential family distributions or independence, etc. These book lack any sort of organic development of a theory behind adding dimensions to a data set or changes in the patterns of symmetry as a data set grows larger--both in dimensions and in the number of observations.

A basic probability text book will begin with a definition of random variables and work its way towards the Central Limit Theorem. While that is good for an intro stats course, there are a lot of problems with assuming normality even in high dimensional situations. 
An example of such a book is:

[Geometric Structure of High-Dimensional Data and Dimensionality Reduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/364227496X)

[Statistics for High-Dimensional Data: Methods, Theory and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642201911)

(Please note that I am not critizing any of the books mentioned. I am just saying that these books don't fit my particular need.)

So what I am looking for is a more analytic look at how probability varies as dimensions get rather high. I use Terry Tao's book as an example of a wonderful development of analysis from basic foundations. I am looking for the same treatment for high dimensional data. I am not sure if I should be looking at a book on measure theory, or calculus on manifolds, or where?

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that a comprehensive book exists yet, high dimensional data analysis is relatively new.  Tao can write a clear, cohesive volume on analysis because real analysis has been very well developed over the last 100+ years.  I would recommend getting familiar with rigorous probability (Billingsley) and stats theory (Wasserman) then reading current research articles.

Comment: @icurays1 Haha. Yes, I am familiar with Billingsley. I can do that. It is interesting that there are so many books out there with the words "High Dimensional" in the title, yet the field is so new as you rightly say. I find that the approaches to high dimensional data lack coherence. From my own studies, approaches like mixture models are fine but they make strong parametric assumptions and there does not seem to be any clear framework on how incremental increases in dimensionality affect probability distributions locally and globally.

Comment: @icurays1 Lasso and Ridge regression are fine but there are so many cases where these methods are still finding spurious results or are sensitive to noise--most notably in genetic models. I am thinking that perhaps some of the work in random matrices might provide some avenue into this confusing picture.

Comment: Did you ever find any books that met your needs? If so, do you mind sharing what you found?

Comment: @MadJack I had a bit of luck. There were two different sets of literature that proved useful. The first looks at nonlinear dimensionality reduction. The book by Wang I cited *Geometric Structure of High-Dimensional Data and Dimensionality Reduction* is a good start. There is also a book *Modern Multidimensional Scaling* by Borg and Groenen.

Comment: @MadJack 
As you get into higher dimensional phenomena, my sense is that the normal "distance" metrics approach of statistics start to breakdown. You have to deal with various artifacts in high-dimensional settings like holes or lower dimensional subspace embeddings, etc. So I have actually found a lot of value in the very new Topological approaches to probability and statistics. There are some articles by Gunar Carlsson on Persistent Homology. There is also some work on stratefied spaces that is great http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3572 .

Comment: @MadJack Sayan Mukherjee at Duke is a good resource--take a look at some of his papers and lecture notes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the resources. I'll definitely check those out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been some time since the question was asked and I believe the recent text "High Dimensional Probability" by Roman Vershynin might be just what you are looking for. It covers a variety of topics, focusing on the concentration phenomenon on higher dimensions. It is both theoretically heavy and intuitionally approachable.

Its current draft is also available for free, in the author's webpage.
https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.html#

Comment: This book does look pretty interesting. Thanks for the recommendation. I have not looked at new resources in a while, so good to find a new and interesting one.

Answer (score 2):

A recently published book by Wainwright, on high dimensional data, which seems useful

[High-dimensional statistics : a non-asymptotic viewpoint](https://books.google.com/books/about/High_Dimensional_Statistics.html?id=8C8nuQEACAAJ)